# I didn't know I had enemies

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I just noticed this. I have never had so many downvotes in one day - some of the posts are several years old:

[image]

I suppose, I can't figure out who did it, or why. Can I do anything at all about it?

Comment: Let's just say that you've had an "effect" on a member(s) of this site

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: LOL

Comment: I will add that the systematic down-vote reversal mechanism is not 100% effective, and I would suggest that if the votes are not reversed in a week's time (or so), contact a moderator via flag with this image and any more pertinent information, and if they agree that further investigation is warranted, they can escalate it to a site employee. This has happened to me, this is what I did, and the votes were eventually reversed.

Comment: By coincidence, I already submitted a vote invalidation request earlier today for the user who appears to have targeted you with downvotes. So, if you get lucky, the script will automatically reverse them all. If not, a staff member will look into it and reverse them manually, when they have a chance. Sorry about this; obviously, targeted downvoting of this nature is against our rules, and we will have a word with the user involved.

Comment: mark them for moderator attention, when the downvotes aren't removed automatically

Comment: As @nbk states, but (importantly and as I have already stated above) ***don't do this immediately***. The script is not run multiple times a day, and no need to flag a moderator for something that will eventually be handled automatically. So, give it time, several days even.

Comment: even when you flag one or two of thbis posts, you will have to wait, also some days, till it is "fixed", because it is done manually, and someone has to take a deeper look in the matter, so be patient, but in your case i believe the automatic system will be triggered, it has only problems with two downvotes at the same time, which it doesn't recognize

Comment: Well, anyway it's just a number on a computer, not something that changes my life in a bad way so I will just wait and see.

Comment: welcome to the club ;) you will get used soon

Comment: Well, I got 10 points back today, so I will just leave it at that.